# Diff tool that ignores floating-point formats (but not values) in text?

Tags: diff, floating-point

I'm looking for a **diff** tool that can also compare floating point values (within some tolerance) in text files. This is in addition to typical text-comparison diff functions, with options to ignore whitespace, ignore case, etc. A GUI (or full-screen console UI) is okay, but I'd really prefer a stream-oriented (stdin/stdout) tool.

Here's an extremely simple example that characterizes the ideal tool. There are 2 versions of foo.c:

foo_v1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI        3.14159265359
#define E_CUBED   20.0855
#define HALF_PHI  0.809f
#define C_SQUARED 89875517873681764.0L

const double AVO = 6.022e23; /* Avocado number */

int main()
{
  printf("%g %g %g %Lg %g\n", PI, E_CUBED, HALF_PHI, C_SQUARED, AVO);
  return 0;
}
```

foo_v2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI        3.14159265358979
#define E_CUBED   2.00855e+1
#define HALF_PHI  8.09e-1f
#define C_SQUARED 8.9875517873681764e18L

const double AVO = 6.022e23; /* Avogadro number */

int main()
{
  printf("%g %g %g %Lg %g\n", PI, E_CUBED, HALF_PHI, C_SQUARED, AVO);
  return 0;
}
```

And here's the diff output I'd expect:

```
$ diff --floats=byvalue --tolerance=1e-9 foo_v1.c foo_v2.c
6c6
< #define C_SQUARED 89875517873681764.0L
---
> #define C_SQUARED 8.9875517873681764e18L
8c8
< const double AVO = 6.022e23; /* Avocado number */
---
> const double AVO = 6.022e23; /* Avogadro number */
```

The second diff (line 8) is the usual text difference; the first diff (line 6) is due to the numbers being outside of the specified tolerance. (The exponent should be 16, not 18, so it's off by 100.0X).

Note that none of the other floating point changes show up as diffs—even though they are text changes, the floating point values do not change beyond the specified tolerance.

Is there a diff tool that can do this?

If not, is there something close, that's open-source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this one, which looks very interesting. I'm trying to have it working on my AIX, so I haven't seem it in action yet, but I believe this is what you (and I :-) need

http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Text/spiff-1.0/

Comment: Wow! Output is **exactly** what I wanted! Btw, the BeOS version [http://www.bebits.com/app/3784] compiled under Cygwin with no changes.

Comment: Well, I am still unable to get it working on AIX. On Linux, gcc-3.3.3 compiled it, but it segfault on the first "spiff Sample.1 Sample.2". On a newer machine, gcc-4.2.4 is angry for:
spiff.c:178: error: static declaration of ‘_Y_doargs’ follows non-static declaration
spiff.c:30: error: previous declaration of ‘_Y_doargs’ was here

Comment: @Davide: If you're still stuck, maybe you should ask a question about it on some website somewhere. ;-)

Comment: Sure, but for now I just asked a friend running Cygwin, and it worked :-)

Comment: Oh man, this is some old school c code...  declares function argument types within the function body, forward function declaration without any arguments... typeless variables that default to int... I'm getting the same error as Davide on debian linux using gcc, but it compiles with one benign warning using icc (intel's c compiler).

Answer (score 12):

The one that I found recently:

http://www.nongnu.org/numdiff/

It's very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

See [Smart Differencer Tools](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer).  These tools compare two source code files according to program structure, as opposed to comparing text lines.  To do so, these tools parse the source file according to the language rules, build an AST, and compare trees.   The output is in terms of abstract editing changes (insert, delete, move, copy, rename) to program structures (identifiers, expressions, statements, blocks, methods, ...).

As a side effect, the individual language lexemes, such as character, string and numeric literals, are converted to a normal form internal representation.  The format of literal is ignored, so it will treat floating point values such as 00.001  and 1e-03 as identical,  0xFF and 255 as identical, and "\n" and "\u000a" as identical.   This doesn't include an tolerance fuzz for floating point numbers, but it does ignore thier shape.  What this means is the the SmartDifference tools will report two corresponding but slightly different numbers as different, but it will only report the numbers themselves; you'll get something like

```
  <Line 75 col 15-19   1.01
  >replace by Line 75 col 15-19 1.02
```

The matcher presently allows *identifiers* to be different and treats a consistent identifier renaming across a scope as a single edit rather that a bunch of different edits.  The idea of using floating point fuzz to allow matching of near-miss fp numbers is interesting; I'll add it to the possible feature request list.

These tools are production for Java, COBOL and C#.  We have preproduction versions for C++ and C; the hard issue is picking up program structures for languages that effectively allow arbitrary editing of the souce via use of macros and preprocessor conditionals.

Comment: Definitely a step in the direction I wanted, and pretty darned cool. I'm curious how the "internal representation" can compare floating-point values without a tolerance. I guess if you're constrained to literals (as opposed to calculation results), the tolerance isn't strictly necessary. But wouldn't it be a nifty feature? ;-)

Comment: @system PAUSE: comparing "internal representations" is easy.  Take the binary floating point value, and compare to the other for equality.  That isn't different than comparing identifiers or string literals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such tool but it would be fairly easy to whip up a Perl script to do that for you by combining some fancy floating point regular expression set with a bunch of routines to normalize said regexed floats. I can probably take a swing at it if you need help, but it's a bit time consuming enterprise so I'll be a greedy pig and ask for a useful bounty.

Comment: Thanks for your offer. Actually I've been looking at writing my own tool for this, but I'm not convinced that regexes are sufficient for comparisons within a specified tolerance.

Comment: If you roll our own, what you want to do is to use Math:: library hierarchy (Math::BigFloat i think) possibly matched with the best floating-point regexp you can find on CPAN or construct yourself - the Perl Regexp book has some nice ones. If you're lucky, Math:: hierarchy has its own parser (have't used it for a while so don't recall).

Comment: A regexp cannot reasonably be bent to compute tolerances.  You need to convert the values to machine floats and compare them.

Comment: @Ira - quite right. Thus the "with a bunch of routines to normalize said regexed floats." part of the answer